# Как отследить событие изменения кастомного селекта и передавать значение атрибута у выбранного значения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, события, select

Сделал кастомный селект, нужно чтобы при изменении значений селекта передавалось значение атрибута у выбранного значения. Как это отследить? Т.е. при выборе "Американский бобтейл" передавалось значение "ABT". Сейчас вообще не удается отловить событие изменения.

```
<select name="breedCat" id="breedCatMale">
   <option value="hide">---</option>
   <option value="ACL">Американский кёрл длинношёрстный</option>
   <option value="ABT">Американский бобтейл</option>
   <option value="BAL">Балинезийская</option>
</select>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.formPhenotypic_select_item select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.addClass('select-hidden');
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    var $list = $('<ul />', {
      'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
      $('<li />', {
        text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
        rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
      }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
      });
      $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });

    $listItems.click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
      $styledSelect.attr('rel', $(this).attr('rel'));
      $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
      $list.hide();
      //console.log($this.val());
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
      $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
      $list.hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Объясните более подробно, что именно хотите сделать?

Comment: Есть 6 взаимосвязанных селектов (все кастомные). Во всех по дефолту пустые значения. Если пользователь выбирает значение в селекте, то при изменении селекта на бэк нужно отправить массив из значений селектов, которые не пустые. Выбирает первый селект - отправляется 1 значение. Выбирается второй - отправляется массив из 2 значений. Но по change не удается отследить изменение значений в селектах и передать их.

Comment: вы убедитесь, что у вас во первых поле `rel` заполняете, потому что `val()` у `option` вызывать сомнительно. А во второых зачем событие клика обрабатывать  на селекте, а не пункте списка в таком случае?

Comment: а.пардоньте, н е дочитал код до конца. есть клики в элементы списка.

Comment: Этот скрипт работает, тут нет проблем. Проблема как вывести значения оттуда при изменении. Этого в скрипте нету.